# Windows Batch to create .txt from a list

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have compiled a list of webstreams in a .txt

E.g..
List.txt

> title of new .txt to be created
>
> contents of new .txt
>
> title of new .txt to be created
>
> contents of new .txt

I was only able to create the .txts using

```
for /f "delims=" %F in (filenames.txt) do copy nul "%F".txt
```

I have very limited programming experience compared to others on this site.
Thank you

Comment: Would be much simpler if the contents of the input file was formatted horizontally instead of vertically.  Line 1: `Filename1.txt,contents of file` Line 2:`Filename2.txt, contents of 2nd file`

Comment: In my opinion, if you're interested in programming and want to continue I suggest you leave batch by the wayside - it's quite limited and unintelligible. Powershell is the "new" windows scripting language that can probably do what you a lot easier

Comment: I could manually change it to that with commas as separators. @nick the language to be used is not an issue, I only learnt a little Java, and dabbled with cmd/batch

Comment: It is a fairly trivial single line of code if the data is formatted horizontally with a comma as the delimiter between the file name and file content. `for /f "tokens=1* delims=," %F in (filenames.txt) do echo %G>"%F.txt"`

Comment: Thanks I'll try that when I get home. Why is it harder for each alternating line to be the 'delimiter' as from a visual point of view that would be the easiest formatting to understand

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Squashman.

`for /f "tokens=1* delims=," %F in (filenames.txt) do echo %G>"%F.txt"`

worked like butter.