# Batch that creates and adds text to a KODI .disc file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Batch that creates and adds text to a Kodi **.disc** file

A **.disc** file is a .txt file used by the **KODI** program.
I have a list in .txt with the following information:

```
File Name 01    Texto AA    Texto AB    Texto AC    Texto AD
File Name 02    Texto BA    Texto BB    Texto BC    Texto BD
File Name 03    Texto CA    Texto CB    Texto CC    Texto CD
File Name 04    Texto DA    Texto DB    Texto DC    Texto DD
```

I need to create files with the name and content of each line.
The result should look something like this:

```
<discstub>
    <title>Texto AA</title>
    <message>Texto AB
    Obs: Texto AC
    Coleção: Texto AD</message>
</discstub>
```

I can now generate the files with this bat

```
@echo off  
CHCP 65001  
PAUSE  
setlocal  
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (02_FilmesSitio.txt) do (type nul>"%%a.disc")  
PAUSE
```

But I don't know the commands or the best way to insert the text in the file when creating it.

**EDIT**
Searching here on Stack I found a comment by @squashman that is perhaps the most suitable course.
In this topic
[Windows Batch to create .txt from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60858825/windows-batch-to-create-txt-from-a-list)

It is a fairly trivial single line of code if the data is formatted horizontally with a comma as the delimiter between the file name and file content. for /f "tokens=1* delims=," %F in (filenames.txt) do echo %G>"%F.txt" – Squashman Mar 26 at 1:10

Each line of my **.txt** file has the 5 necessary information.
On the line they are separated by TAB.
But they can be separated by a comma or semicolon, or some other character.
At the beginning the text for the file name.
Then, separated by TABs the texts for each line of the file.
So my question is: What should I modify and/or add to my current **.bat** file?

Comment: `ECHO` is the command you would use with the redirection to output to your file: `echo This is a test >file.txt`

Comment: Searching here on Stack I found a comment by @Squashman that is perhaps the most suitable course.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60858825/windows-batch-to-create-txt-from-a-list

Comment: Please @Squashman , post the 2 files here. filenames.txt and file.bat. Nothing I do is working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is resolved.
**List_Movies.txt**

```
Movie Title 1 (YEAR) complement;Text Message 01;Text Message 02;Text Message 03
Movie Title 2 (YEAR) complement;Text Message 01;Text Message 02;Text Message 03
Movie Title 3 (YEAR) complement;Text Message 01;Text Message 02;Text Message 03
```

**CreateDISCfileWithText.bat**

```
@echo off
CHCP 65001
PAUSE
setlocal

for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=;" %%F in (List_Movies.txt) do (type nul>"%%F.disc"
  echo ^<discstub^>>>"%%F.disc"
  echo  ^<title^>%%F^<^/title^>>>"%%F.disc"
  echo  ^<message^>%%G>>"%%F.disc"
  echo  %%H>>"%%F.disc"
  echo  %%I^<^/message^>>>"%%F.disc"
  echo ^<^/discstub^>>>"%%F.disc"
)
PAUSE
```

**Result:**
**.disc** file with text. Example:
File title: **Movie Title 1 (YEAR) complement.disc**
Content

```
<discstub>
    <title>Movie Title 1 (YEAR) complement</title>
    <message>Text Message 01
    Text Message 02
    Text Message 03</message>
</discstub>
```

**KODI Feature**
https://kodi.wiki/view/Media_stubs